# How to change thumbnails creation way in cs-cart

Tags: thumbnails, crop, cs-cart

When cs-cart creates square thumbnails it fills empty space with some given color. How to make cs-cart crop image to create thumbnails?
 1. The way cs-cart does
 2. The way i would like to do

[1. The way cs-cart does 2. The way i would like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wqxq.jpg)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 addons exist: [https://marketplace.cs-cart.com/autoimage-lite.html][1] [https://marketplace.cs-cart.com/product-image-uploader.html][1] [https://marketplace.cs-cart.com/cs-cart-smart-image-cropper-add-on.html][2]
If you have question, i can help you. All addons i have.

Comment: AutoImage Lite
I think it will fit what i need, is it compatible with 4.10.3? I have written some code and it works but it could be also interesting

Comment: You can write me in skype - stasok.com